# How to post pictures on page walls using Facebook Android SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, post, sdk, image

I've tried thousands of ways, but none works. Every time the post will not appear. I have managed to post text before, but the image never works ...

```
     try {
            String response = facebook.request("me");
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

            String DIRECTORY_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/img/img.jpg";
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(DIRECTORY_PATH);
            byte[] data = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            data = baos.toByteArray();
            parameters.putString("message", "picture caption");
            parameters.putByteArray("source", data); //I try "picture" too

            String pageid = "152390368241461";
            response = facebook.request(pageid + "/photos", parameters, 
                    "POST");
            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                    response.equals("false")) {
               Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
           }
            showToast(getResources().getString(R.string.sucessharefc));
     } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: Help-me :/ I need for complete a work

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Graph API Page docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos) you need to make a `multipart/form-data` POST using a token with `publish_stream` and `manage_pages` permissions.

The [Facebook Android SDK request()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/request/) docs say of the form of `request()` you're using:

> Note that binary data parameters (e.g. pictures) are not yet supported by this helper function.

So you'll have to use an HTTP client library for this.

Answer (score -1):

You are using deprecated APIs from the Facebook SDK. Download the latest version [here](https://developers.facebook.com/android/), and look through the Getting Started guide and various tutorials.

To upload a photo, you should use the [Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request) class, in particular the [Request.newUploadPhotoRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#newUploadPhotoRequest%28Session,%20Bitmap,%20Callback%29) method.

Answer (score -1):

```
Bitmap imaBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.androidface);
byte[] data = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
imaBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
data = baos.toByteArray();
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message"," Facebook App Testing");
params.putByteArray("picture", data);
mAsyncRunner.request("1741449412743375/photos", params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```